# Mysql pull a count, and group by that count

Tags: mysql, sql

Hard to explain exactly what I need.  What I'm trying to do is do a count of the top 5 winners this month.  The way the table is structured (open to changing it) is that it records every game played, the ids of the players, the winner, and the date.

Table structured as follows: id, p1id, p2id, dateAdded, status, winner.

Here's my pull:

```
 SELECT COUNT(winner) AS totalCount FROM gameEnders 
 WHERE 
 status=0 AND 
 (YEAR(dateAdded) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(dateAdded) = MONTH(CURDATE())) 
 GROUP BY winner
 ORDER BY totalCount DESC LIMIT 5
```

I knew when I did it that this wouldn't work, but this was my best guess.  What I want to display is 3 and then 1 (going to add player names with a join later).  There are 3 entries of winner id:2, and 1 entry of winner id:1.  What does display is 2, which is the id of the highest numbered winner.

Tried to be as clear as possible with what I'm trying to do.  If this is possible, or if anybody needs more information let me know.

Comment: Search "top N per group". It's a pretty common SQL problem with many well-known solutions.

Comment: Not really sure how to do that, I am unfamiliar with top per group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `winner` to the select statement and you should have a descending order list of winners this month...

```
Select winner, 
       Count(*) AS totalCount 
From   gameEnders 
Where  status=0 
And    Year(dateAdded) = Year(CurDate()) 
And    Month(dateAdded) = Month(CurDate())
Group By winner
Order By Count(*) DESC 
Limit 5
```

Comment: Use `COUNT(*)` rather than `COUNT(winner)`.

Comment: Good catch, was just redoing the formatting and noticed it as you posted.

Comment: Still just displaying 2.  I echo totalCount and/or winner and both echo 2.

Comment: Can you show your php, and/or try this query in phpMyAdmin or whatever you are using?

Comment: winner 2  totalCount 2
from phpmyadmin

Comment: What do you store in winner? the playerID? or 1/2 depending on who won?

Comment: the player ID, and my mistake status was supposed to be 1 :p... You got it fixed for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT winner
from
(
SELECT 
    winner, 
    COUNT(*) AS totalCount 
FROM gameEnders 
WHERE status=0 AND (YEAR(dateAdded) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(dateAdded) = MONTH(CURDATE())) 
GROUP BY winner
) ranked_winners
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT 5;
```